# How to Permission give to close for user not allow to upload photo in wordpress?

Tags: linux, wordpress

How to Permission give to close for user  not allow to upload photo in wordpress ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [WP Upload Restriction](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-upload-restriction/)  or [Adminimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/) plugin for this, you also can apply the simple snippet to disable the media button for other user besides admin user.

```
/*Remove Add media Buttons*/

function RemoveAddMediaButtons(){
if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
remove_action( 'media_buttons', 'media_buttons' );
}
}
add_action('admin_head', 'RemoveAddMediaButtons');
```